# Print the disappeared hovered numbers in the order that the user mouseover them using Java Script

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover

I made this webpage, where random numbers appear from 1 to 9 in square divs.

[image]

What I need is:
When the user mouseover any number, the number will disappear, finally when the user finishes hovering all of the numbers, an alert should appear displaying all the numbers in the order that the user hovered.

Here is my attempt:
I could only make the numbers disappeared, but how can I print them in an alert in the same order that the user hovered:

```
document.getElementById("s1").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s1").style.visibility = "hidden";})
document.getElementById("s2").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s2").style.visibility = "hidden"; })
document.getElementById("s2").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s2").style.visibility = "hidden"; })
document.getElementById("s3").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s3").style.visibility = "hidden";})
document.getElementById("s4").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s4").style.visibility = "hidden";})
document.getElementById("s5").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s5").style.visibility = "hidden";})
document.getElementById("s6").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s6").style.visibility = "hidden";})
document.getElementById("s7").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s7").style.visibility = "hidden";})
document.getElementById("s8").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s8").style.visibility = "hidden";})
document.getElementById("s9").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
document.getElementById("s9").style.visibility = "hidden";})
function alertAfterHovering() {
alert(document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML+" "+document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML+" 
"+document.getElementById("s3").innerHTML+" "+document.getElementById("s4").innerHTML+" 
"+document.getElementById("s5").innerHTML+" "+document.getElementById("s6").innerHTML+" 
"+document.getElementById("s7").innerHTML+" "+document.getElementById("s8").innerHTML+" 
"+document.getElementById("s9").innerHTML)
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using eventListener and using some dynamic code:

```js
var squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

for (square of squares) {
  square.addEventListener("mouseenter", addNumber);
}

var total = [];

function addNumber(e) {
  if(e.target.textContent) {
    total.push(e.target.textContent);
    e.target.textContent = "";
    if(total.length === squares.length) {
      alert(total);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.square {
  width: 29%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00ffff;
  margin: 2%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 33%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
  <div class="square">3</div>
  <div class="square">4</div>
  <div class="square">5</div>
  <div class="square">6</div>
  <div class="square">7</div>
  <div class="square">8</div>
  <div class="square">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is good. I was trying to let the OP figure out more of this on their own.

Comment: yes true, but sometimes OP is not enough confident with JS to know dynamics binding and callbacks

Comment: Can I make them squares instead of rectangles?

Comment: it was just to create an example, you can style them as you prefer, it won't have any impact on the javascript

Answer (score 1):

Create an array to capture the numbers as the user hovers. Then use that array to display the alert.

```
var numbers = [];
// repeat this for each element Or find a better way of targeting the elements so you don't have to hard code for each one
document.getElementById("s1").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    var thisNumber = document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML;
    // you need some way of making sure hovering over an invisible element does not add a duplicate to the array
    if (!numbers.includes(thisNumber) {
        numbers.push(thisNumber);  
    }
    document.getElementById("s1").style.visibility = "hidden";
});

function alertAfterHovering() {
    alert(numbers);
}
```

Comment: No. Don't use duplicate IDs that's not good HTML and can cause problems. Targeting by class or attribute is possibly the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Or give the parent an ID and loop target it's children.